# Are there English figurative expressions equivalent to Japanese idiom 馬耳東風 meaning a person who doesn’t listen to other’s advice?

Tags: idiom-requests, proverb-requests

North wind tells the arrival of spring season in Japan. And incidentally, we  have an idiom, “馬耳東風,” of which literal translation is ‘the east wind to the ears of horse,’ meaning a person who doesn’t listen to, or respect other’s opinion, advice, and suggestion like a horse is insensitive to the meaning and tastefulness of east wind. 
For example, we say “His boss’s admonition was just an east wind to Taro. And he was fired.”

I don’t know why it should be east wind, not west, south or north wind, but Chines have the same saying, “东风吹马耳.”

The structure of “East wind to a horse” resembles “Pearls to a swine,” but is pretty different in meaning.

Are there similar figurative expressions to describe a person who has deaf ears to others' advice and opinion, like an obstinate or insensitive horse?

Comment: Actually, from what you've described, "...Pearls before swine," is pretty equivalent.  It means:  good advice is wasted on people too ignorant to heed it.

Comment: @Oldbag. I thought ‘East wind to ‘Horse’s ears’ and ‘Pearls before swine’ are in the neighborhood, but have a bit different nuance of meaning as I noted. For instance, ‘Apple stock is a pearl before me who don’t invest in stocks’ doesn’t necessarily match ‘The stockbroker’s solicitation was the east wind to a horse to me – It came in one ear and went out the other.”

Comment: I have wondered why in the game of Mah Jongg, the player who is seated in the position of the East Wind both wins and loses double. Perhaps there is something about the East Wind in Asian culture that I do not know.

Comment: @tchrist. I haven’t played mah-jongg long time. So I forgot most of its rules. I don’t remember the rule that the player who picked up 東牌 tonpai –East tile when deciding the seat wins and loses double. I thought the picker of the east tile first picks the ‘pai’ out of the pile of 24(?) pais on the table.

Comment: @YoichiOishi Well, they may be American rules; I have only ever played here, never in Asia when I have travelled there. However, you are correct in recalling that the picker of the east tile is the first picker also, at least as it is played here.

Comment: @tchrist. I played mah-jongg many times with local people in various places in China when I was studing in Beijing. The rules of the game were almost same with Japanese rules, and I used to win more than lose.

Comment: If you look up the etymology of 馬耳東風, it says 東風 refers to "spring wind" here.   (Did you mean "east wind" in your first sentence?  Isn't north wind associated with winter, not spring?)  As in, the "even if the warm spring wind blows on a horse's ears, the horse doesn't seem to enjoy the pleasant feeling (like a human would)."   One reference in Japanese: http://kotowaza-allguide.com/ha/bajitoufuu.html

Comment: To me, "pearls before swine" refers to a *situation* in which someone fails to appreciate the great beauty, wisdom or worth of something; it is both too general for this case, and praises the bosses advice too much (unless it was really sagacious). Incidentally, doesn't Japanese have 猫 に 小判 ("a gold coin to a cat"), which is an almost perfect translation of "pearls before swine"?

Comment: @Oldbag, according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cast_pearls_before_swine), the phrase means "To give things of value to those who will not understand or appreciate it." This is clearly not synonymous.

Comment: @Beta. 猫 に 小判 ("a gold coin to a cat"),  is an exact English counterpart to 'pearls before swine." We also have an idiom,"馬の耳に念仏ーIntoning the name of Amitabba (Pureland Buddha) to  horse's ears, " which is more synonimous to  馬耳東風.

Comment: Well, if the person asks for your advice and then ignores it, they are "askholes".  Hope this helps!

Comment: @tchrist, In India, East wind (पुरवाई ) heralds the rain, and traditionally agricultural societies would obviously have a special affinity for signs of rains. Just a conjecture on the significance of East Wind in Japanese and Chinese cultures as well.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

We do have an expression, "***in one ear and out the other***"

> His boss's admonition *went in one ear and out the other* and he was fired.

One could also say, "His boss's admonition ***fell on deaf ears***.

Comment: [*fall on stony ground*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fall+on+stony+ground) also.

Comment: "in one ear and out the other". This is simply wrong. This describes a easily distracted, attention poor child, not a "obstinate or insensitive horse".

Comment: I agree.  not listening to your boss *is* wrong. If he'd listened to his boss, he'd still have a job. :)

Comment: Well, there are two answers here. *Fell on deaf ears* is OK. But *in one ear and out the other* does not capture the same spirit as what is being asked in the question. If something goes in one ear and out the other, it's not so much that the person who owns the ears is obstinate; it's that the person who owns the ears is either forgetful or not paying attention.

Comment: @Jim: You can be fired for being obstinate or for being scatterbrained. You've captured the wrong one with the main part of your answer.

Comment: In my view someone can either have something go in one ear and out the other ***or*** they can ***let*** it go.  In the latter they may have chosen to do so for a number of reasons including lack of respect, disregard for authority, laziness, improper analysis of possible outcomes etc.  Regardless of why it happens the result is that they don't take it to heart and they let it go in one ear and out the other.  Perhaps I should edit the example to "He let his boss's admonition go in one ear and out the other."

Answer (score 17):

If you just [look up the English translation here](http://beta.jisho.org/search/%E9%A6%AC%E8%80%B3%E6%9D%B1%E9%A2%A8), you get

> utter indifference; talking to the wall; praying to deaf ears

In the US, I don't hear "praying to deaf ears" as a common expression, though "fell on deaf ears", as mentioned in another answer is.  The second phrase, or a slight variant---"talking to a wall"---is also very common in the US.  For example,

> I tried to tell him how unhealthy that was, but it was like *talking to a wall*.

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, *talking to a **brick** wall* is a stronger expression (and is also very common).

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+like+talking+to+a+brick+wall

Comment: Thanks for pointing "talking to wall" expression. I've never heard it and we use literally same expression in polish. For me, this makes it easy to remember and use.

Answer (score 9):

Continuing with the horse motif:

*[You can lead a horse to water, but you cannot make it drink it.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/you+can+lead+a+horse+to+water+but+you+can%27t+make+it+drink)*

That is, you can lecture someone but, your words may not have accomplish the desired effect.

*The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms*

Comment: Shouldn't that be "You can lead a horse to water, but you cannot make it drink"?

Comment: And then there was the Dorothy Parker, "You can lead a horticulture, but you can't make her think."

Answer (score 3):

*[Seed sown along the path](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matthew%2013%3A19&version=NIV)* is a reference to Jesus' [parable of the sower](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matthew%2013&version=KJV):

> When anyone hears the message about the kingdom and does not
>   understand it, the evil one comes and snatches away what was sown in
>   their heart. This is the seed sown along the path. *Matthew 13:19 NIV*

In the more familiar KJV it was *[seed by the wayside](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matthew%2013%3A19&version=KJV)*:

> When any one heareth the word of the kingdom, and understandeth it
>   not, then cometh the wicked one, and catcheth away that which was sown
>   in his heart. This is he which received seed by the way side. *Matthew
>   13:19 KJV*

*His boss’s admonition was just seed sown along the path. And he was fired.*

Answer (score 1):

Jim's answer is perfect for a situation when someone is ignoring a *particular* opinion or piece of advice.

But if you're talking about someone who *routinely* ignores the advice/opinions of others, you might call them a [maverick](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/maverick), or a [lone wolf](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lone+wolf).

Comment: Or a loose cannon.

Comment: I might say that they *keep their own counsel* if I thought that was a good thing, or I might call them a *stubborn old fool* if I thought that was a bad thing.

Comment: single-minded or close-minded would also fit for someone who is adamant about having their own way, disregarding advice given

Comment: Except that a _maverick_ can be used in a complimentary way – someone who doesn't just go along with the crowd.

Comment: Or *pig-headed*.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar vein, Jesus is quoted as saying, on numerous occasions,

> Whoever has ears, let them hear."— Matthew 13:9

I would suppose that most of the people Jesus was addressing not only had ears, but had ears that worked. So the fact that Jesus felt it necessary to, repeatedly, encourage his audience to “*listen-up!*” would seem to indicate that his exhortations were aimed at people who had a tendency to pay no heed to what they heard.

Answer (score 1):

A person who doesn’t listen to, or respect other’s opinion, advice, and suggestion is a *[know-it-all](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/know-it-all)*:

> n. someone who gives the impression of knowing everything.
>
> *McGraw-Hill's Dictionary of American Slang and Colloquial Expressions*

Or also possibly strong-headed, arrogant and stubborn.

Answer (score 1):

There is "You can't tell that guy anything. He marches to his own drummer".

or

"Giving him advice is like teaching French to a pig.  You waste your time and annoy the pig".

Comment: That's a variant of something very relevant to an unmoderated Usenet group I knew: "Do not mud-wrestle a pig – you get dirty and the pig enjoys it."

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, and I'm inventing, in part: "**[playing/being] a Trojan to one's Cassandra."** See [Cassandra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassandra).

Now, in terms of English idioms, [**"have blinders on,"**](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ytJNRDL0zDgC&pg=PA33&dq=%22blinders%22%20idiom&hl=en&sa=X&ei=s-QYVfaADujnsAT8uYCwCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22blinders%22%20idiom&f=false) touches on what you want, too.

Comment: [That's `blinkers` in English](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blinker).

Comment: @John Mee, per Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dict, they are equivalent for one of the meanings of __blink·er__
noun

2
a (1) :  __blinder__ 1 (2) :  a cloth hood with shades projecting at the sides of the eye openings used on skittish racehorses — usually used in plural

Comment: In American English, it would indeed be blinders.

Answer (score 0):

It's just come to me while I was trying to be helpful to someone. It was clear the person had already made their mind up, and wouldn't listen to any advice that either contradicted or challenged their opinion.

Sometimes it's a question of pride, low self-esteem or just sheer bloody mindedness! :-)

**There's none so deaf as those who will not hear**

> [**Proverb**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/There%27s+none+so+deaf+as+those+who+will+not+hear). If you tell someone something that he or she does not want to know, he or she will not pay attention to you.
>   **There's none so deaf as those who will not hear**  *proverbial saying, [mid 16th century](http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/deaf.aspx), used to refer to someone who chooses not to listen to unwelcome information*.
>
> The proverb was first recorded in **1564**, with different wording "*[Who is so deaf, or so blind, as he that willfully will neither hear nor see](https://books.google.it/books?id=fgaUQc8NbTYC&pg=PA260&lpg=PA260&dq=There%20are%20none%20so%20deaf%20as%20those%20who%20won%27t%20hear&source=bl&ots=eUz5bfswI3&sig=7XSl7RZvociIva2Nj78YlDhPwTo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1bgiVd6DOsiRsAGNpYPQBA&ved=0CFgQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=There%20are%20none%20so%20deaf%20as%20those%20who%20won't%20hear&f=false)"* but a French equivalent was in use 200 years earlier.
>
> <sup>Sources: The Free Dictionary; Encyclopedia.com; *The Facts on File Dictionary of Proverbs* By Martin H. Manser</sup>